# SQL why use isnull(field, '') <> ''?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sql-server-2000, string

I'm reviewing some code I've inherited, and I found a line like this:

```
And isnull(IH.CustomerItemNumber, '') <> ''
```

Which one of my predecessors seems to have used in a ton of where clause or join clauses.  It looks to me like this is an unnecessary calling of a function, and therefor a performance hog, because NULL will never equal the empty string '', right?

Specifically I took this out of a join clause in a particular query and performance increased dramatically (from 46-49 secs to between 1-3).

Replaced it with `AND IH.CustomerItemNumber <> ''`

Is my assessment correct here?  This is redundant and slow and can be removed?  In what situation might this code be beneficial?

EDIT:  So, can NULL ever equal the empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the code is there may be because of the history of the application.  Perhaps at some point in time, NULLs were allowed in the field.  Then, these were replaced with empty strings.

The reason the code is inefficient is because of the optimization of the join.  `ISNULL()` and its ANSI standard equivalent `COALESCE()` generally add negligible overhead to the processing of a query.  (It does seem that in some versions of SQl Server, `COALESCE()` evaluates the first argument twice, which is a problem if it is a subquery.)

My guess is that the field has an index on it.  SQL Server knows to use the index for the join when the field is used alone.  It is not smart enough to use the index when included in a function call.  It is the join optimziation that is slowing down the query, not the overhead of the function call.

Personally, I would prefer the form with the explicit NULL check, if the performance is the same:

```
IH.CustomerItemNumber <> '' and IH.CustomerItemNumber is not null
```

Being explicit about NULL processing can only help you maintain the code in the future.

Comment: +1, I was about to talk about being explicit and how isnull will change the query plan.  Best answer right here.

Comment: Ok, so will SQL Server be able to use the index if the statement is split apart?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will, but you need to check for your particular case (you can look at the query plan to see if the index would be used).  As I say, explicitness is nice for maintenance, but not when it affects performance.

Comment: @MAW74656, yes it can use the index.

Comment: The split is performing faster than the original code.  So is `Field IS NOT NULL` in general a better choice than `isnull(field)` because it can use Index?

Answer (score 5):

This is semantically the same as:

```
And IH.CustomerItemNumber <> '' And IH.CustomerItemNumber Is Not Null
```

So it is checking that the column is both not null and not an empty string. Could be important.

**UPDATE**

In this case, because we're looking for non-equality of a string literal (empty string), you have at least three semantically correct options:

- `And IH.CustomerItemNumber <> ''`
- `And IH.CustomerItemNumber <> '' And IH.CustomerItemNumber Is Not Null`
- `And isnull(IH.CustomerItemNumber, '') <> ''`

The first is going to return the same result set as the other two because `<> ''` will not match a null, regardless of the [ansi_nulls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) setting.

In a quick test on a dev system, both the first and the second utilized an index seek.  The first is *very slightly* outperforming the second in one of a few *very simplified* tests.

The third, since it adds a function call, may not utilize indexing like the others, so this is probably the worst choice.  That said, in a quick test, isnull was able to use an index scan.  Further adding `Is Not Null` to the third choice actually sped it up and moved it to an index seek.  Go figure (GO! GO! Query optimizer!).

As with @Gordon, I would also choose the second option most times since it would better state my intent to other developers (or myself) and would be a better practice to follow if we were checking equality against another column which could be null (think of potential ansi_nulls off).

For completeness' sake:

- `And nullif(IH.CustomerItemNumber, '') is not null`
- `And case when IH.CustomerItemNumber = '' then null else IH.CustomerItemNumber end is not null`
- `And case IH.CustomerItemNumber when '' then null else IH.CustomerItemNumber end is not null`

Are all interpreted exactly the same way (as far as I can tell) in SQL Server and perform the same as the third option above.

Comment: @MAW74656 Is the field IH.CustomerItemNumber nullable? If not, then the ISNULL function may not be necessary. If it is nullable then the test may need to be in the code depending upon what else the code is doing.

Comment: The field is nullable, although there are 0 null values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for NULL Checking:

```
And (IH.CustomerItemNumber IS NOT NULL) AND (IH.CustomerItemNumber <> '')
```

BTW,
 **[ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) - Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.**

In your case, if the value of IH.CustomerItemNumber is null then it will be replaced by empty value which will then be compared with empty string.

Comment: So... a null value will not get returned in my code, or with the modified version you and everyone else here has?

Answer (score 0):

> because NULL will never equal the empty string '', right?

NULL is also never *not equal* to the empty string... it's both at once and neither all at the same time. It communicates a state where you just don't know for sure.

Comment: So what does SQL Server do?  It must chose, it must either return these values, or reject them.  Which is it?

Comment: Based on this fiddle, looks like SQL Server will through away the values.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef55f/9

Comment: @MAW74656 Correction: use this fiddle that also shows correct NULL comparisons. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef55f/15